# There is no public key available for the following key IDs 1397BC53640DB551

Tags: apt, updates

When I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got this following warning:

```
There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 1397BC53640DB551
```

This is the only warning I got and I do not get any Error.

How I can fix it and what the key 1397BC53640DB551 is all about?

Comment: For reviewers: There are already 2 votes on https://askubuntu.com/questions/766205/update-information-is-outdated-16-04 being a duplicate of this one. Let's not create a loop!

Comment: Can you please include the full output of `apt-get update` in your question?

Comment: You can check this [SO](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308760/w-gpg-error-http-ppa-launchpad-net-precise-release-the-following-signatures/) thread for solution. Link to [related site](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

**I resolved running:**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
```

The command above download the missing key using the hexadecimal numbers given in the error (1397BC53640DB551) with apt-key. After running apt-key to download the missing PUBKEY, any packages from that repositories will be considered trusted.

---

It seems to be a known problem in chromium that is being worked on (check [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596074)). They are working to remove SHA1 encryption ([link](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Apt/Sha1Removal)).

Another possible workarounds that have been posted on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/4grdo7/an_error_occurred_w_there_is_no_public_key/)

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Looking at [this](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/), seems that Google now has two keys, and the old one will probably be discontinued along with SHA1.

Comment: The first one timed out for me (keyserver.ubuntu.com) so I had to use the second one from Google.

Comment: If you're in an IPv6 only server, you can use `pool.sks-keyservers.net` instead of `keyserver.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Working fine when I can't add inkscape trunk in this tutorial https://inkscape.org/es/gallery/item/6641/view/ The error appear: "W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/trunk/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9DA4BD18B9A06DE3
" Then I Add with this: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9DA4BD18B9A06DE3

Comment: For me this command worked: `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551`

Answer (score 46):

Correct command line is:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
```