# I cannot watch streaming video with firefox 47.0 on 14.04

Tags: firefox, video, flash

I am able to use Firefox to watch videos on some sites such as Youtube or Dailymotion (perhaps these are HTML5?) but I cannot watch video or listen to streaming audio on sites such as cnn.com, cbc.ca or a whole bunch of other broadcast media sites. (Adobe Flash?)

I find it very annoying that I need to watch these with Chrome.

I tried installing `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` and `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` but got nowhere.

I tried following the instructions here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2236146

but when I run the command `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to retrieve status information from google : W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
```

I try the instructions here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-fresh-player-plugin-in-ubuntu.html

but the instructions tell me to "create a symbolic link for Pepper Flash to /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so", but they do not say where to put this symbolic link!  I copied the file named "freshwrapper.conf" to `~\.config` and nothing happened.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is no public key available for the following key IDs 1397BC53640DB551](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766883/there-is-no-public-key-available-for-the-following-key-ids-1397bc53640db551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem's been resolved since firefox switched to html5 ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just use the Firefox (NPAPI) version.  To install the version for Firefox, run:

```
sudo apt install flashplugin-installer
```