# Upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Forgive me but I am a n00bie at troubleshooting Ubuntu and this is really my first try at upgrading.

I am running into a number of errors when I run 'sudo apt update' specifically the following out of a long list of Hit and Get results:

```
  Err:2 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                         
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
```

-- is there a command I can run that will fix this? if so what is it?

```
  Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
```

--how would I figure out how to resolve these 404 errors? Is there a place to go to find the live IP?

```
  Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
  Err:13 https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7373B12CE03BEB4B
```

--I uninstalled this so I'm not sure how to track it down!

```
  Err:20 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gabor-karsay/parlatype/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
```

and then there's this block:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059

W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7

E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7373B12CE03BEB4B

E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gabor-karsay/parlatype/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
```

How do I pick this apart? Where do I even start? I'm not afraid of the terminal but I'm terrified of nuking my machine by accident! Can someone help me break this into a series of bite size chunks or point me to resources to understand what I'm looking at better? I just found the man pages website and have yet to understand how to navigate it enough to find what I need! I figure if I can resolve most if not all of the above errors I can get past the upgrade errors I have too. It hangs on the second step pointing me to a "network error".

Tried: digging through Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, several Ubuntu tutorial sites, bumped into the online copy of the man pages (I have yet to figure out how to use the terminal to get them and navigate them there), turning off the Live Updater, changing the settings, changing what server from a specific one to a general (I think) server.

I'd truly love to upgrade and any assistance or resources would be fantastic. If I can clarify anything please let me know and I'll do my best!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is no public key available for the following key IDs 1397BC53640DB551](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766883/there-is-no-public-key-available-for-the-following-key-ids-1397bc53640db551)

Comment: You've got numerous errors of different causes...  I also note mention of *trusty* or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which reached EOSS (*end of standard support*) back in 2019-April at the end of it's five years of life; unless you're trying to explore infected systems, I'd be more careful with your adding 3rd party repositories (where all security rests with you).

Comment: If you want to view the reference manual page for the `apt` command, just use `man apt`.  Some commands have a number of pages available (giving an extra dialog asking which page/type you want to view), but most don't.  You added one PPA I noted (ie. 3rd party *Personal Package Archive*) where security checks are your job, you should have scanned https://launchpad.net/~gabor-karsay/+archive/ubuntu/parlatype which is the instructions & quickly noted there is no support for your release & it's unwise to add it (*unless exploring malware/infections*)

Comment: You have lines that reference [Ubuntu 21.10 which is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/); they'll provide nothing useful for later releases - unless you're trying to  explore malware attacks.  You also do realize `apt upgrade` and `apt full-upgrade` will only apply upgrades & security fixes to your system, with different commands (eg. `do-release-upgrade`) which perform *release-upgrades* from one release to another.  The codename for 22.04 is *jammy* (a J), *impish* was 21.10 or the release before it, *kinetic* or a K 22.10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Key issue fixed-- THANKS!

Comment: Key issue fixed-- THANKS!
I started my journey with Ubuntu in July of this year where did the Ubuntu 14.04 stuff come from? 
Now that I know what a PPA *is* and how to check it, I'll be more diligent for sure! Which brings me to how do I get rid of that PPA?
Out of the upgrade commands which one do I want and how would I determine this in the future?
What should I know about the sourceslist errors, anything?
I really appreciate the help. Knowing what to look up and where is incredibly helpful!

Comment: The 14.04 is the line with *trusty*; ie. the 2014-April release had the codename of *trusty* (many releases ago when T was the letter).  You possibly read something and just copied it into your sources file  (*it's safer to read & understand what you're adding first*). You can remove the source (delete the line in your sources), disable it (add a "#" to the start of the line so it's treated as a comment & ignored) & for clues also read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu or https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file